# Combine two message payload

Tags: node-red

I'm using node-red on one of my projects. And I'm having trouble handling two message payloads in one node. I DO NOT want to deal with them SEPARATELY, instead I want this node to combine both inputs into ONE. 
All the answers I found online were talked about how to deal with them in sequence, I DO NOT want that. I need to make them into ONE message payload and pass to the next node.
Anyone has any insight on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `Join` node.

[image]

This can be set to combine 2 incoming messages so that the new msg.payload is an array containing the msg.payload of the input messages.

[image]

Comment: I don’t think this is what I’m looking for. Join only combine message from one node. In this case, I’m combining from two nodes.

Comment: Just wire the output from the 2 nodes into the input of the join node

Answer (score 0):

Do also check out node-red-contrib-fusion which may or may not be overkill depending on your specific use case.